# group by two values and select only rows with earliest and latest value

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

My dataframe sample:

```
label timestamp           trip_num trip_direction 
1001  2023-10-05 03:43:18 8        0                 
1001  2023-10-05 03:44:42 8        0              
1001  2023-10-05 03:46:29 8        1              
1001  2023-10-05 03:47:54 8        1              
1001  2023-10-05 03:56:29 8        1              
1001  2023-10-05 03:57:24 8        0              
1001  2023-10-05 03:58:55 8        0              
1001  2023-10-05 04:12:33 8        0          
1001  2023-10-05 04:13:45 8        1            
1001  2023-10-05 04:53:08 8        1         
1003  2023-10-05 05:53:18 10       0            
1003  2023-10-05 05:54:42 10       0             
1003  2023-10-05 05:56:29 10       0             
1003  2023-10-05 05:57:54 10       1           
1003  2023-10-05 06:06:29 10       1           
1003  2023-10-05 06:07:24 10       0          
1003  2023-10-05 06:08:55 10       0          
1003  2023-10-05 06:22:33 10       0          
1003  2023-10-05 06:23:45 10       1          
1003  2023-10-05 06:54:08 10       1
```

the code to create it:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(label = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001,
                           1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003),
                 timestamp = c('2023-10-05 03:43:18', '2023-10-05 03:44:42', '2023-10-05 03:46:29', '2023-10-05 03:47:54', '2023-10-05 03:56:29',
                               '2023-10-05 03:57:24', '2023-10-05 03:58:55', '2023-10-05 04:12:33', '2023-10-05 04:13:45', '2023-10-05 04:53:08',
                               '2023-10-05 05:53:18', '2023-10-05 05:54:42', '2023-10-05 05:56:29', '2023-10-05 05:57:54', '2023-10-05 06:06:29',
                               '2023-10-05 06:07:24', '2023-10-05 06:08:55', '2023-10-05 06:22:33', '2023-10-05 06:23:45', '2023-10-05 06:54:08'),
                 trip_num = c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                 trip_direction = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1))
```

I want to group by `label`, `trip_num`: take the earliest `timestamp` value for each pair of `label` and `trip_num` where `trip_direction = 0`, then the newest value for the same pair but `trip_direction = 1` but before 1 changes to 0 in the column, and calculate the `timestamp` difference between those rows so that I get duration. And keep only `trip_direction = 0`  values. The expected output below:

```
label timestamp           trip_num trip_direction delta_t 
1001  2023-10-05 03:43:18 8        0              00:13:11   
1001  2023-10-05 03:57:24 8        0              00:55:44
1003  2023-10-05 05:53:18 10       0              00:13:11   
1003  2023-10-05 06:07:24 10       0              00:46:44
```

Comment: Please provide the data in a format to work with

Comment: @Ludwig added reproducible dataframe to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to a tidyverse-based approach, you could try:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

df %>% 
  group_by(label, trip_num, grp = cumsum(trip_direction != lag(trip_direction, default = 0)) %/% 2) %>% 
  slice(c(1, n())) %>% 
  mutate(delta_t = as_hms(lead(timestamp) - timestamp)) %>% 
  drop_na(delta_t) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

This returns

```r
  label           timestamp trip_num trip_direction  delta_t
1  1001 2023-10-05 03:43:18        8              0 00:13:11
2  1001 2023-10-05 03:57:24        8              0 00:55:44
3  1003 2023-10-05 05:53:18       10              0 00:13:11
4  1003 2023-10-05 06:07:24       10              0 00:46:44
```

I added `as.data.frame()` to show `delta_t` in your desired format. The `tibble()`-version (just remove the `as.data.frame()`-part) looks like this:

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  label timestamp           trip_num trip_direction delta_t
  <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>          <dbl> <time> 
1  1001 2023-10-05 03:43:18        8              0 13'11" 
2  1001 2023-10-05 03:57:24        8              0 55'44" 
3  1003 2023-10-05 05:53:18       10              0 13'11" 
4  1003 2023-10-05 06:07:24       10              0 46'44"
```

So, what happend here?

- First we created an auxiliary grouping column based on the changing of trip_direction. This was necessary to meet your *before 1 changes to 0* condition.
- Next we took the first and the last row of these grouped data using `slice`.
- The final steps are simply calculating the difference, dropping rows containing `NA`s, removing the auxiliary column and the grouping.